# Dealing with "403 Forbidden" when fetching a subreddit RSS feed from a Go application

Tags: go, http, rss, reddit

I’m trying to fetch a subreddit RSS feed from my Go application but I get the response code "403 Forbidden” every time and a message to contact support through email.

The weird thing is the request works if I do it directly in an HTTP client

```
GET https://reddit.com/r/investimentos/best/.rss?sort=new
User-Agent: MyRssClient/1.0 (Operated by BurnInNoia)
```

But using Go it fails with the message:

> If you're supplying an alternate User-Agent string, try changing back to default as that can sometimes result in a block.

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "MyRssClient/1.0 (Operated by BurnInNoia)")
resp, err := u.client.Do(req)
```

Does anyone have done it before?

Comment: Where you able to fix this?

Comment: No @RyanKnopp, used https://github.com/turnage/graw instead

Answer (score 0):

`old.reddit.com` appears to work while the same subreddit on `reddit.com` will return a 403 forbidden.